# Hide non-tagged elements in CSS

Tags: css

```
<div id="foo">
    <a id="bar1">show me</a>
    hide me
    <a id="bar2">hide me too</a>
</div>
```

How do I use CSS (`display:none;`) to only have the first `a` element visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This *won't work*](http://jsfiddle.net/rHVz4/):

```
#foo {
    display: none
}
#bar1 {
    display: block
}
```

[This works](http://jsfiddle.net/rHVz4/1/), but `visibility: hidden` has it's own downsides:

```
#foo {
    visibility: hidden
}
#bar1 {
    visibility: visible
}
```

`display: inline-block`/`block` is seemingly required to make this [work in IE8](http://jsfiddle.net/rHVz4/3/).

That's the closest you can get without [changing your HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/rHVz4/2/):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="foo">
    <a id="bar1">show me</a>
    <span>hide me</span>
    <a id="bar2">hide me too</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#foo span, #bar2 {
    display: none
}
```

Comment: The `visibility` trick works! Are the downsides cross-browser issues?

Comment: That's not what I was thinking of. I meant that elements with `visibility: hidden` still take up "visual space" on your page, whereas elements with `display: none` don't. It doesn't seem to matter in this case. The requirement for `display: inline-block` in IE seems to be a quirk of nesting `visibility: visible` inside `visibility: hidden`.

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways that I've found to allow this, the first:

```
#foo {
    font-size: 0;
}

#bar1 {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pwrMp/).

And the second:

```
#foo {
    font-size: 0;
}

#foo :first-child {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pwrMp/1/).

These methods work, pretty much, by giving the `font` a size of `0`, so it occupies no height, or width. And then overriding that `font-size` on specific elements, to cause the text of those specified tags to be shown. The problem with, and the reason I don't like, this method is that it explicitly requires a fixed-size font (`16px` in the examples) to override the inherited `font-size` of `0`. Still, they both work, though the latter example is probably a tad too fragile to be trusted with dynamically generated mark-up.

Comment: +1 for a *sneaky idea*. I feel sure that some browser (probably an old version of IE: not sure) will still somehow show text that has `font-size: 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, since #bar1 is a child of #foo. If you want the text of foo hidden, then #bar1 will be hidden too.

Comment: This could be worked around, however, if the middle `hide me` were inside of a `<span>` or other element.

Comment: Good to know it's not possible. I'm dealing with injected HTML and was looking for a non-JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given that structure you really can't, since there is no way to tag the "hide me" text without hiding the container div. You'd really have to have something along the lines of:

```
  <div id="foo">
    <a id="bar1">show me<a>
    <span>hide me</span>
    <a id="bar2">hide me too</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't successfully cascade a style that hides all content within a container except a specific child element.

You would need to contain the words "hide me" in a `<span />` or similar in order to use something like `div#foo:not(#bar1) { display: none; }` but even there I'm not sure about what browsers you need to support.

**Edit**
Actually, on second thought, you might get away without wrapping your text in span tags if you can get away with using the `:not()` pseudo class.